# Is there a way with Rails/Postgres to get records in a random order BUT place certain values first?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, random

I have an app that returns a bunch of records in a list in a random order with some pagination.  For this, I save a seed value (so that refreshing the page will return the list in the same order again) and then use `.order('random()')`.

However, say that out of 100 records, I have 10 records that have a `preferred_level = 1` while all the other 90 records have `preferred_level = 0`.

Is there some way that I can place the `preferred_level = 1` records first but still keep everything randomized?

For example, I have `[A,1],[X,0],[Y,0],[Z,0],[B,1],[C,1],[W,0]` and I hope I would get back something like `[B,1],[A,1],[C,1],[Z,0],[X,0],[Y,0],[W,0]`.

Note that even the ones with `preferred_level = 1` are randomized within themselves, just that they come before all the `0` records.  In theory, I would hope whatever solution would place `preferred_level = 2` before the `1` records if I were ever to add them.

### ------------

I had hoped it would be as intuitively simple as `Model.all.order('random()').order('preferred_level DESC')` but that doesn't seem to be the case.  The second order doesn't seem to affect anything.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got the job done for me on a very similar problem.

```
select * from table order by preferred_level = 1 desc, random()
```

or I guess the Rails way

```
Model.order('preferred_level = 1 desc, random()')
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint!

I ended up trying `.order('preferred_level DESC, random()')` and it also took care of having additional levels like "2" come before "1".

I didn't even bother trying putting the preferred level sort before the random sort since I thought that the random would just totally jumble it up again.  

Thanks again!